# Matlab mark datetime plot with text

Tags: matlab, datetime

I have a problem with the text() function  in Matlab.

I have a plot and need to mark/label certain points. The X-Axis is a time axis automatically adjusted by Matlab because I use datetime as X input.

Strangely I cannot use text() while simply converting with datenum.

Is there a way to do this?

```
t1 = datetime(2013,11,1,8,0,0);
t2 = datetime(2013,11,5,8,0,0);
t = t1:t2;
y = 1:5;
hold on
plot(t, y);
% wrong x position -> not visible
text(datenum(t1), 0, 'Test');
```

(hope there is no error or it is working ;), typing this on my phone)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain the code you tried (this is called a [mcve]), and add a screenshot or two showing what you want to achieve and how it's not good now.

Comment: Have you tried 'datetick'?

Comment: If I use datenum instead of datetime for the x-axis, I loose the automatic rescaling function (updating labels while zooming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using t1 directly?

```
t1 = datetime(2013,11,1,8,0,0);
t2 = datetime(2013,11,5,8,0,0);
t = t1:t2;
y = 1:5;
hold on
plot(t, y);
text(t1, 2, 'Test');
text(t2, 2, 'Test2');
```

[image]

The XAxis is a DatetimeRuler (see [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.decorator.datetimeruler-properties.html)) and no NumericRuler (see [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.decorator.numericruler-properties.html)) and therefore misinterprets your datenum double number.

```
get(gca,'XAxis')
ans = 
  DatetimeRuler with properties:

             Limits: [1×2 datetime]
         TickValues: [1×5 datetime]
    TickLabelFormat: 'MMM dd'

  Show all properties
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I made a mistake using datetime and/or giving text a wrong argument.